# no cudnn 6.0 for cuda toolkit 9.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, nvidia, cudnn

trying to install tensorflow gpu on windows 10 since three days.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support

says :

> If you are installing TensorFlow with GPU support using one of the mechanisms described in this guide, then the following NVIDIA software must be installed on your system:
>
> - CUDA® Toolkit 9.0. For details, see NVIDIA's documentation Ensure that you append the relevant Cuda pathnames to the %PATH% environment variable as described in the NVIDIA documentation.
> - The NVIDIA drivers associated with CUDA Toolkit 9.0.
> - cuDNN v6.0. For details, see NVIDIA's documentation. Note that cuDNN is typically installed in a different location from the other CUDA DLLs. Ensure that you add the directory where you installed the cuDNN DLL to your %PATH% environment variable.
> - GPU card with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0 or higher. See NVIDIA documentation for a list of supported GPU cards.

[image]

I downloaded cuda toolkit 9.0 from archives.
but there is no cudnn 6.0 for cuda 9.0 here : https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download
It's driving me mad, as only thing available there is cudnn v7.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: could you point me in the right direction. 
I just want to be able to use tensorflow gpu on my windows 10. (I have an nvidia m1000m gpu lenovo p50)

Comment: I think I figured it out the tensorflow documentation on the website is out of date/ https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/install/install_windows.md it says cudnn 7.0 i'll try that

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I cant comment... but I am having this exact same issue! Tensorflow has conflicting requirements for install. Cuda Tookit V8.0 is the last supported version for cudnn V6.0

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/install/install_windows.md

Comment: Turns out I just installed both versions and set the PATH variable to the cudnn version called for. It looks like it's working great now.

Comment: bme too, somehow it started working. Don't know how or why!!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who comes to this thread with issues on cudNN or cudart errors, here's a few notes:

1. Tensorflow documentation may or may not be updated quickly enough after a new release.
2. Tensorflow can be compiled (built) from scratch, which allows you to decide what CUDA and cuDNN version to use, so if you are using a pre-compiled binary, you will need the version of CUDA and cuDNN it was built for.
3. You need to have cuDNN in the path.
4. Tensorflow's documentation for installing a binary will always specify the version of CUDA and cuDNN it needs.

   - If things don't work, try running a simple hello world tensorflow program and read the errors to know what version of CUDA / cuDNN to use.
   - For example, a missing cudart64_81.dll needs the 64 bit version of CUDA 8.1.
   - A missing cudnn64_6.dll needs cuDNN 6.0

CUDA can be downloaded from: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive
cuDNN can be downloaded from: https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive